# What does「やや巻きで進行中」mean?

Tags: meaning, phrases

What does「やや巻きで進行中」mean?

"やや" literally means "slightly" and looking up "巻き" I keep getting "roll", which is probably not the intended meaning here. So by guessing I assume the phrase means "It is progressing slowly or gradually". Please guide me towards a better understanding of this phrase.

Answer (score 3):

巻き is a 業界用語 that means 予定時間より早いこと (earlier/faster than planned).

Its verb form is 巻く.

These are used (usually in 撮影, 放送, イベント etc.) this way:

> 巻きでお願いします。 (≈ 速めにお願いします・急いでください)
> 今日は巻いてる。 (≈ 予定より早めに進んでいる)

Its antonym is 押す.

> 今日は押してる。 (≈ 予定より遅れている)
> ５分押してます。 (≈ 予定より５分遅れている)